# Java JOptionPane text unreadable

Tags: java, swing, text, fonts, windows-8.1

Here's a picture of what it ends up looking like.

[image]

I don't think it's a problem with the code as it's copied straight from the tutorial website. I've reinstalled JDK, as well as run it in command line and Eclipse. Any possibilities? The code is

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Swag {

    public static void main ( String[] args) {
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your name?");

        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How old are you?");
        int age = Integer.parseInt(input);

        System.out.print(" Hello, " +name);
        System.out.println("Next year you'll be " +(age+1));
    }
}
```

but I don't think it's an actual code problem, I tested out another sites usage of it and the text still looks like that.

Comment: Wow. I'm seriously curious about what's causing this. What font is that? Which OS are you using? Java compiler and VM vendor and version? Did you do anything weird to your computer?

Comment: by default all default Fonts in Win8 are accepted in Java in Java6/7/8 (green color) without additional info (I've reinstalled JDK) isn't this question answerable

Comment: I'm running windows 8, latest JDK, nothing weird done to my computer that I know of.. Tell me how to get any other info you need!

Comment: I've seen similar things with OpenJDK on Linux that was fixed with `-Dsun.java2d.xrender=true` or `-Dsun.java2d.opengl=True` added on the command line.  Don't know how relevant this would be to windows, but couldn't hurt to try I guess?

Comment: I've tried googling that but nothing even comes up, and it obviously doesn't work on CMD any knowledge on the Windows version of that?

Comment: The OpenGL one is not Linux specific: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html

Comment: Okay so I did the java -Dsun.java2d.xrender=true FILE in cmd and the first pop up looks error free, and then when I start typing the stuff i'm typing starts bugging, and then all of the text.

Comment: @mKorbel Maybe the OP had some fancy custom font. But this is a bit out of my league, I guess. I was just asking for more information - because it probably isn't with the code the OP included - so others would have what they'd need to solve it.

Comment: @11684 Thanks for trying anyway :) Are there any other places I could post this to try and get help?

Comment: is this problem happened only with java programs or with all graphical programs in windows 8 ?

Comment: @MCHAppy I have not experienced this problem anywhere else besides this.

Comment: @user3647851 AFAIK StackOverflow is the best place you could have asked this question. The only other option I could think of is filing a bug report with Oracle. But if nobody has answered this after a few days I'll add a (small) bounty (unless someone else has done that already by then).

Comment: I FIXED IT! For those who are curious or people in the future that will have this problem, I went into my nvidia control panel and added eclipse to it, and overrode the integrated driver to use my nvidia, and now it works fine! Thanks for all the help

Comment: @user3647851 Answering your own question is encouraged on StackOverflow. It would get you a chance to earn some upvotes and it would show the community the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 5):

**Remark:** *Since the solution has been posted as a comment more than a month ago I'll repeat it as an answer so that the question doesn't show up as unanswered anymore.*

Here is the quote from the comment:

> I FIXED IT! For those who are curious or people in the future that will have this problem, I went into my nvidia control panel and added eclipse to it, and overrode the integrated driver to use my nvidia, and now it works fine! Thanks for all the help (user3647851)