# JOptionPane Dialog boxes not displaying correctly in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, joptionpane

I'm using Java 12.0.2 on Eclipse 2019-09, and recently I've come across JOptionPane dialog boxes refusing to display. I've tried with Eclipse 2019-06 but to no avail, I've tried with different file and class names, and with different eclipse-workspace locations too.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

EDIT: Using the "Show Command Line" button I got this:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin\javaw.exe -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\Michael\eclipse-workspace\test\bin" test.test

I am on Windows 10 Home, Version 1903. I forced the OpenGL rendering GPU in Nvidia control panel to my dedicated GPU but it didn't change a thing. I also added the JDK's \bin location to PATH in environment variables and set JAVA_HOME correctly too, but nothing changed.

Here's the code I used:

```
package test;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "test");
    }

}
```

Which gives this result:
[image]

Comment: Swing GUIs whould be started on the EDT. Do that, and if it still fails, [edit] to add a [mre].

Comment: Works for me. What is your OS (i.e. Windows) version? I am on Windows 10. Have you changed anything in the Windows configuration? Post the _java_ command that _Eclipse_ uses to run your `test` class. See button _Show Command Line_ in the _Run Configurations_ dialog window in _Eclipse_.

Comment: It could very well be a problem with Swing and your video card. Please check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23715057/java-joptionpane-text-unreadable)

Comment: If you run it from the command line (in the _Run Configuration_ there is a _Show Command Line_ button), do you get the same? I doubt it is related to Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found a "solution" of sorts. I found that the problem isn't with Eclipse, as a .jar I ran similarly only showed a white blank box and crashed, just like with JOptionPane in the image above.

What I did was I installed the 32-bit Java 8u231 JDK, configured Eclipse to use it instead of 12.02, and bada-bing the JOptionPane window displayed correctly and didn't crash.

The .jar I previously tried running also worked perfectly ***after*** I uninstalled JDK 12.02

It's still a mystery as to why only the 32-bit JDK seems to work, I will continue researching and troubleshooting, but in the meanwhile, if anyone has a similar issue, here's how I (temporarily and imperfectly) solved it.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDOa6.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXQkm.png)

EDIT: By re-installing windows, I was able to get the 64-bit JDK to work. Everything is back to normal, hopefully the problem doesn't arise again.